# LoadPostData NameValueCollection does not include all controls on postback

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, custom-controls

I have created an asp.net custom User Control

```
public class InputMask : CompositeControl, IPostBackDataHandler, IPostBackEventHandler
```

if for instance, the custom control is within a div

```
<div runat="server" id="inputArea>
    <asp:MaskInput runat="server" ID="ssn" ToolTip="SSN" Format="SSN" PartialMask="true" />
</div>
```

and in code behind I have this:

```
 inputArea.Visible = False
```

On postback `LoadPostData(string postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)`postCollection does not have the MaskInput key.

if I do this:

```
inputArea.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none")
```

postCollection contains the MaskInput key.

I understand when using css to hide the div, the control is rendered but not displayed. Whereas, when using visible=false, the controls is not rendered at all.

So, is there a workaround to getting the key in LoadPostData when using visible=false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix resolve this issue:

I changed the LoadPostData method from:

```
public override bool LoadPostData(string postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) {
        this.Text = postCollection[ClientID + InputHiddenPostfix];
        return false;
    }
```

to

```
public override bool LoadPostData(string postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) {
        var key = ClientID + InputHiddenPostfix;
        string text = this.Text;
        if (postCollection.AllKeys.Any(k => k.Equals(key))) {
            string item = postCollection[key];
            if (this.ReadOnly || text.Equals(item, StringComparison.Ordinal)) {
                return false;
            }
            this.Text = item;
        } else {
            return false;
        }           
        return true;
    }
```

Also changed the Text property to use ViewState

From:

```
    [Bindable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
```

to

```
    [Localizable(true)]
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.EncodedInnerDefaultProperty)]
    [WebCategory("Appearance")]
    [WebSysDescription("MaskBase_Text")]
    [Bindable(true, BindingDirection.TwoWay)]
    [DefaultValue("")]
        public string Text {
        get {
            string item = (string)this.ViewState["Text"];
            if (item != null) {
                return item;
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
        set {
            this.ViewState["Text"] = value;
        }
    }
```